# How to check is property right from interface type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have this method in class:

```
class BinderScoreService<T> extends Binder {
  public bindTeacher<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
  }
}
```

When I use it I pass string value as parameter, then typescript checks if it is key of type `T`:

```
bindTeacher('id');
```

How to pass another parameter and to do the same?

Like this:

```
bindTeacher<ISecond>('id', 'second');
```

I tried this:

```
public bindTeacher<K extends keyof T, KB extends keyof B>(key: K, key2: B) {
}
```

And calling:

```
bindTeacher<ISecond>('id', 'second');
```

Comment: If you want to check if something is a key of type `T`, then do `keyof T`.  As in, `KB extends keyof T`.  And there is no `B` type anywhere, right?  If `key` is of type `K`, then `key2` should be of type...

Comment: Yes, I need to be ensure that I pass right string that presents in interface type

Comment: Could you share an sample?

Comment: I don't think I can until you make this into a [mcve].  What is `ISecond`?  Why do you want to manually specify `ISecond` to `bindTeacher()` instead of either inferring it or hardcoding it in `BinderScoreService`?  I don't want to spend too much time making an example that doesn't match your use case, and I can't figure out your use case from this code.

Comment: I pass two generic types, then two parameters, I need to be ensure that both parameters are related to generic types, that it is keys of generics types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
    public bindTeacher<K extends keyof T>(...keys: K[]){
    }
```